# How to detect wake from sleep in the browser on iOS/Android?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, dom, browser

I want to be able to refresh the page when the user returns to page from a different tab or by waking the device.

I could have sworn that I read somewhere that the `pageshow` event would be fired from the window, but that turns out not to be the case.

`window.onfocus` seems to do the trick, but I would like to have confirmed if this works reliably or if there is a more appropriate way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the right answer is to listen for the `visibilitychange` event from the document, and then to test for the `hidden` property on the document.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API):

```
// Set the name of the hidden property and the change event for visibility
var hidden, visibilityChange; 
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") { // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support 
  hidden = "hidden";
  visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "mozHidden";
  visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "msHidden";
  visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "webkitHidden";
  visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}

var videoElement = document.getElementById("videoElement");

// If the page is hidden, pause the video;
// if the page is shown, play the video
function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document[hidden]) {
    videoElement.pause();
  } else {
    videoElement.play();
  }
}

// Warn if the browser doesn't support addEventListener or the Page Visibility API
if (typeof document.addEventListener === "undefined" || 
  typeof document[hidden] === "undefined") {
  alert("This demo requires a browser, such as Google Chrome or Firefox, that supports the Page Visibility API.");
} else {
  // Handle page visibility change   
  document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);

  // Revert to the existing favicon for the site when the page is closed;
  // otherwise the favicon remains paused.png
  window.addEventListener("unload", function(){
    favicon.change("/favicon.ico");
  }, false);

  // When the video pauses, set the favicon.
  // This shows the paused.png image
  videoElement.addEventListener("pause", function(){
    favicon.change("images/paused.png");
  }, false);

  // When the video plays, set the favicon.
  videoElement.addEventListener("play", function(){
    favicon.change("images/playing.png");
  }, false);

  // set the document (tab) title from the current video time
  videoElement.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    document.title = Math.floor(videoElement.currentTime) + " second(s)";
  }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the event focus can help you here

```
$(window).focus(function() {
//do_something
```

});
or if you want to bind some other events like mousemove

```
$('*').bind('mousemove click mouseup mousedown keydown keypress keyup submit change mouseenter scroll resize dblclick', function () {
//do_something
```

});

Comment: This should be answer for question. Work very well on IOS too. Thanks you